# Single form multiple submit into same array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, post

I was trying to push with a single form using the `$_POST` method multiple times the same form (with different values) until the array index is 4 (or a number I decide).

So with this [html form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlnZO.png) i want to press submit, push the values into array, then refresh page, reinsert different values and so on until the condition is true.

```
<?php
if (!isset($count)) {
    $person = array(
        array(
            'name' => '',
            'surname' => '',
            'phoneNumber' => ''
        )
    );
}
var_dump($person);
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    echo "<form action=\"index.php\" method=\"post\">
        <label for=\"name\">Name</label>
        <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" required>
        <br>
        <label for=\"surname\">Surname</label>
        <input type=\"text\" name=\"surname\" required>
        <br>
        <label for=\"phoneNumber\">Phone Number</label>
        <input type=\"text\" name=\"phoneNumber\" required>
        <br>
        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" name=\"submit\">
    </form>";
    $count = 0;
} else {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $phoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber'];

    if (count($person) <= 2) {
        array_push($person, $name, $surname, $phoneNumber);
        //echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\">";
        //echo "Sto inserendo persone";
        //echo count($persone);
        echo count($person);
        //var_dump($persone);
        //print_r($persone);
    } else {
        var_dump($person);
    };
}

?>
```

I was thinking about using `$_SESSION` but I don't have an idea about how to use it.

I don't want to use AJAX or jQuery or Javascript only pure PHP.

Comment: *push the values into array* look into `array_push()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below shows always the form and your actual persons array. If you submit the form, your data will add to the array until it counts more than three entries. I think that is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['persons'])) {
    $_SESSION['persons'] = [];
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (count($_SESSION['persons']) <= 2) {
    $_SESSION['persons'][] = array(
      'name' => $_POST['name'],
      'surname' => $_POST['surname'],
      'phoneNumber' => $_POST['phoneNumber']
    );
  }
}
?>

<pre><?php var_dump($_SESSION['persons']); ?></pre>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" required><br>
  <label for="surname">Surname</label>
  <input type="text" name="surname" required><br>
  <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
  <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" required><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

With the following line of code you can clear you array if you need to:

```
$_SESSION['persons'] = [];
```